# Suppressing module output when extracting CSS with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I am trying to use webpack 4 to compile `.scss` files and extract them into a separate file with `mini-css-extract-plugin`.

The relevant parts of my webpack config include:

```
entry: {
  'styles': './sass/styles.scss',
  ...
},
module: {
  rules: [
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      'css-loader',
      'sass-loader'
    ]
  },
  ...
},
plugins: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'css/[name].css',
    chunkFilename: "[id].css"
  }),
  ...
],
output: {
  filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
}
```

I am seeing both `css/styles.css` *and* `js/styles.bundle.js` emitted. Is there any way to suppress `js/styles.bundle.js`? I have already attempted to use `suppress-chunks-webpack-plugin` with no luck (neither the .css or .js is emitted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Webpack Extraneous File Cleanup Plugin](https://github.com/AnujRNair/webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin)

Install using npm or yarn

```
npm install webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin --save-dev
yarn add webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin --dev
```

In your `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const ExtraneousFileCleanupPlugin = require('webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new ExtraneousFileCleanupPlugin({
      extensions: ['.js']
    })
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that as an alternative to the plugin suggested by davcs86, [Remove Files Webpack Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remove-files-webpack-plugin) might also be worth considering for this use case - it allows deletion of files based on name or regexp before or after the build.